# The closed form for $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+m)}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Just for fun, I defined the following series. For $m\in\Bbb N$, 
$$g_m=\sum_{n\geq1}\prod_{i=0}^{m}\frac1{n+i}$$
I am seeking a closed form for $g_m$. I found $g_1,\ g_2$, and a general expression involving a lot of integrals.

$$
\begin{align}
g_1=&\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1{n(n+1)}\\
=&\sum_{n\geq1}\frac1n\int_0^1 t_0^n\mathrm{d}t_0\\
=&\sum_{n\geq1}\int_0^1\int_0^{t_0} t_1^{n-1}\mathrm{d}t_1\mathrm{d}t_0 \\
=&\int_0^1\int_0^{t_0}\sum_{n\geq0}t_1^{n}\mathrm{d}t_1\mathrm{d}t_0 \\
=&\int_0^1\int_0^{t_0}\frac{\mathrm{d}t_1}{1-t_1}\mathrm{d}t_0 \\
=&1 \\
\end{align}
$$
Through the same process, it can be shown that $g_2=\frac14$. In fact, through the same process, it can be shown that 
$$g_m=\int_0^1\int_0^{t_0}\int_0^{t_1}\cdots\int_0^{t_{m-2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t_{m-1}}{1-t_{m-1}}\mathrm{d}t_{m-2}\cdots\mathrm{d}t_2\mathrm{d}t_1\mathrm{d}t_0$$
Which I don't even know how to approach. Any ideas? Thanks.

**This isn't a duplicate question, because I would like to know how to evaluate those nested integrals, if possible.**

Answer (score 1):

The sum telescopes:
$$\frac{m}{x(x+1)\cdots(x+m)}=\frac1{x(x+1)\cdots(x+m-1)}
-\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m)}.$$
Summing this from $1$ to $\infty$ gives
$$m\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+m)}
=\frac1{(m-1)!}$$
so your sum is $1/m!$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)\ldots(n+m)}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n(n+1)\ldots(n+m-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+m)})$, which can be easily verified by adding the fractions. From here, you can define $V_{n}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)\ldots(n+m-1)}$, and so clearly

$$g_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(V_n-V_{n+1})$$ and from here it is fairly obvious what to do